# Anycubic i3 Mega layers don't stick together/are too thin

Tags: extruder, bed-leveling, hotend, nozzle

My Anycubic i3 Mega suddenly stopped printing properly. As you can see on the images attached, the printed filament seems to be too thin which causes the layers to not stick together.

I already:

- cleaned the extruder
- replaced the hotend (the old one was quite dirty)
- leveled the bed
- increased the printing temperature (bed from 55 °C to 60 °C, nozzle from 200 °C to 215 °C and later 230 °C)

[image: Printed model with thin lines and gaps between the lines]

Comment: Is the ring supposed to be solid from inner diameter to outer? Conversely, should the gaps between the rings be there?

Comment: It is difficult to see if it is under extrusion or if the initial gap is too large. Do you have a better image?

Comment: I get this characteristic in the first few layers if the initial z-height is too high. Is the nozzle flattening out the extrusion or is it still round as extruded?

Comment: I have increased the extruder speed to 130%, now its working. Still no idea why...
And @fred_dot_u the gaps shouldn't be there